# Python Memory Error when generating pairs using itertools.combinations

Tags: python, list, compiler-errors, out-of-memory

I have an int list with unspecified number. I would like to find the difference between two integers in the list that match a certain value.

```
from itertools import combinations

#Example of a list
intList = [3, 6, 2, 7, 1]
diffList = [abs(a -b) for a, b in combinations(intList, 2)]

#Given if difference = 2    
print diffList.count(2)
```

The code snippet worked but when a larger list is given, I am getting MemoryError. Can anyone tell me if there's something wrong with the codes or the error is due to my hardware limitation?

Comment: How long the list could be?

Comment: @MostafaR - possibly in hundreds. The combinations could run into thousands..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem using this code:

```
result = 0
for a, b in combinations(intList, 2):
    if abs(a - b) == 2:
        result += 1
print result
```

So your problem is not just your hardware limitations, it's your hardware limitations and bad code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I didn't take into account that I could run into the possibility of generating far too much than the memory can handle. I see that there's a different way to get the same results.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly how large is "a larger list"?  If `len(intList)` is `n`, `len(diffList)` will be `n*(n-1)//2` (the number of combinations of `n` things taken 2 at a time).  This will consume all your memory if `n` is large enough.

If you only care about the value 2,

```
print sum(abs(a-b) == 2 for a, b in combinations(intList, 2))
```

is one way to do it that consumes very little memory regardless of how large `intList` is.  However, it will still take **time** proportional to the square of `len(intList)`.

Comment: This solution is a very smart one.

Comment: It isn't actually a difficult trick at all, but it's a very useful trick that will help you many times. So, if you don't understand why this works, it's worth trying to figure it out. My answer attempts to explain effectively the same trick, but step by step.

Answer (score 3):

You created a list with a list comprehension, then called its `count` method. Instead, just create an iterator with a generator expression, then call an `icount` function that takes any iterable:

```
diffs = (abs(a -b) for a, b in combinations(intList, 2))
print icount(diffs, 2)
```

It's nearly identical to your original code, but it doesn't use any extra memory.

---

Of course that `icount` function doesn't exist, but you should be able to write it yourself.

```
def icount(iterable, value):
    result = 0
    for element in iterable:
        if element == value:
            result += 1
    return result
```

… or …

```
def ilen(iterable):
    return sum(1 for _ in iterable)
def icount(iterable, value):
    filtered = (elem for elem in iterable if elem == value)
    return ilen(filtered)
```

… or …

```
def icount(iterable, value):
    return sum(elem == value for elem in iterable)
```

… or (using [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)) …

```
def icount(iterable, value):
    return quantify(iterable, lambda elem: elem == value)
```

---

If you want, you can merge the expression into the `icount` function and do it all in one line, and then you have exactly Tim Peters' answer.